# .net Upgrade Assistant migrated the project to .net Standard 2.0, How to change it to .net6?

Tags: upgrade, migrate

The project is in .net Framework 4.6.
Trying to upgrade in .net 6, Using .net Upgrade Assistant console.

Using command 'upgrade-assistant upgrade **--target-tfm-support LTS** <.csproj>'
But it is upgrading to .net Standard 2.0.

What is the reason?
How to resolve?

Comment: Just replace `netstandard2.0` with `net60` in the csproj file. If the generated code is compatible with .NET standard, it's compatible with .NET 6 too

Comment: @Pieterjan, Thanks for your reply, It worked. Will it work for vice a versa case, Means from net 6 to .net Standard 2.0?

Comment: Not necessarily. .NET Standard is only for building class libraries which can be consumed both by .NET Framework/.NET Core applications. This means that framework/sdk/runtime/platform-agnostic APIs (Like [`AppDomain`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/net-framework-tech-unavailable), ClickOnce, ...) are not available in .NET Standard. However since we now have a runtime for .NET applications for each platform (Windows, Linux, MacOS, Android) aka .NET 6 etc, we don't need .NET Standard anymore. But the previous link shows APIs that cannot be used in .NET 5-6-7-...

Comment: @Pieterjan Thank you for the all details. Agreed for the platform related, but needed reference in .net framework project.

Comment: It all depends on what code you're using. If you're calling before-mentioned api's then you have no choice but to target .NET Framework. If not, then you may be able to target .NET standard.

Comment: Just try targetting .NET Standard and see if the project still builds. If it doesn't, then you have no choice but to target .NET Framework.